# Como guardar datos de un checkbox en una tabla de la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql

He probado de varios formas que he investigado y ninguna me funciona y haber si me puede explicar cual es el error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form class="cloro" action="guarcloro.php" method="POST">
        <center>
            <h1>Prueba de Guardar Checkbox</h1>

                    <div class="checkbox">

            <input type="checkbox" id="act1" name="exa[]" value="Hemograma">
            <label for="act1">Hemograma</label>


            <input type="checkbox" id="act2"  name="exa[]" value="Orina">
            <label for="act2">Examen Orina</label>&nbsp;
        </div><br >

        <input type="submit" name="aceptar" value="Guardar">
        </center>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

archivo de guardar.php

```
<?php
include "conexion/db.php";

$calidad=$_POST['exa'];
foreach ($calidad as $key => $valor) {

    $query="insert into check( Hemograma, Orina) values('$valor')"; 
    $resul= $cone->query($query);

    if($resul){
        echo "Datos guardados correctamente";


    }else{
        echo"No fue posible guardar los datos";
    }
}
?>
```

Lo que quiero es que haya un checkbox que capture un dato para cada campo en este caso solo serian dos campos

Comment: Primero tienes que entender que un check box únicamente guarda 0 y 1 como valor, si lo que deseas hacer es que si activan un check box (orina por ejemplo), guarde en un campo de la bd "Orina Realizado" (por ejemplo), deberás de crear una función en jquery o javascript (dependiendo qué estés usando), para poder capturar si el checkbox que deseas está o no marcado, luego de eso decidirás qué deseas ingresar en la BD. Por favor amplía un poco más tu pregunta para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Bueno, lo del jquery lo investigare gracias, pero en este caso me gustaria saber porque no me deja guardar? no importa por ahorita si solo me muestra 0 o 1 podrias decirme como podria hacer para que me permita guardar

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes el campo en tu bd?

Comment: Ya lo hice amigo el problema era el nombre que le había dado a la tabla gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No le estas pasando los valores necesarios en el insert.

```
insert into check( Hemograma) values('$valor');
```

o

```
insert into check( Hemograma, Orina) values('$valorx','$valory');
```